# Datastax 4.8 Search node - cqlsh connection error

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

I've recently installed on a three node cluster DSE 4.8.9. The cluster was running fine and was healthy. We've started deleting 4 million records out of 14 millions, so created quite some tombstones. 
After restarting one of the nodes (10.0.106.7), the node is not exposing port 9042 anymore so i can't connect via cqlsh . Port 7199 is exposed.

The machines setup: 150 GB data drive, 10 GB commitlog on a seperate disc, 32 GB RAM, 8 cores

- cassandra.yaml: listen_ and rpc_address is set to the same IP.
- cassandra-en.sh: HEAP is set to 22 GB (machine has 32 GB RAM)

I'm observing quite a high GC activitiy in the system.log. you can see the [system.log](http://pastebin.com/ndeHycZ5)  on pastebin

this seems to cause that c* is not exposing port 9042 anymore.

I've tried to let the machine run in this state for several hours. The systemlog stays active, but cqlsh is not able to connect. I'm receiving

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.106.7': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('10.0.106.7', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

when connecting from the same host to cqlsh.

This leads to the issue, that opscenter can't connect to this instance.

Any suggestions what else I can do to bring cqlsh on this node back?

UPDATE:
output of nodetool status:

```
UN  10.0.106.5  80.46 GB   1       ?       ec3f6f84-41bc-4ae5-85a1-59df023308a7  rack1
UN  10.0.106.6  67.02 GB   1       ?       47388e88-6079-4926-95a6-f4e7627a2037  rack1
UN  10.0.106.7  87.47 GB   1       ?       651c6633-0948-499c-8f7a-98041c87cfb2  rack1
```

UPDATE2:

> netstat -an | grep 9042
>   returns nothing
>
> excerpt from output.log

```
INFO  20:37:37,178  Loading settings from file:/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
INFO  20:37:37,287  Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=; cluster_name=Gjallarhorn-Public-Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/srv/commitLog; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=8192; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/srv/cassandra/data]; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=3074457345618258602; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=10.0.106.7; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=1; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=10.0.106.7; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/srv/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=10.0.106.5,10.0.106.6,10.0.106.7}]}]; server_encryption_options=; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  20:37:37,345  DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  20:37:37,402  Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 5632MB
INFO  20:37:37,402  Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 5632MB
INFO  20:37:37,406  Detected search service is enabled, setting my workload to Search
INFO  20:37:37,407  Detected search service is enabled, setting my DC to Solr
INFO  20:37:37,408  Initialized DseDelegateSnitch with workload Search, delegating to com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch
```

> ps -ef|grep cassandra

```
 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre//bin/java -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=29450 -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=29450 -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms22G -Xmx22G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/dse/cassandra/hotspot_compiler -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra -Dcassandra.storagedir= -Dcassandra-pidfile=/var/run/dse/dse.pid -cp :/usr/share/dse/dse-core-4.8.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-hadoop-4.8.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-hive-4.8.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-search-4.8.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-spark-4.8.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-sqoop-4.8.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/HdrHistogram-1.2.1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-runtime-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-asn1-ber-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-i18n-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-client-api-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-codec-core-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-codec-standalone-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-extras-aci-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-extras-codec-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-extras-codec-api-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-model-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-net-mina-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-util-1.0.0-M33.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/asm-5.0.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-pool-1.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guava-16.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guice-multibindings-3.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/janino-2.6.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/java-uuid-generator-3.1.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jbcrypt-0.4d.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/journalio-1.4.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/kmip-1.7.1e.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/log4j-1.2.13.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/mina-core-2.0.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.antlr-2.7.7_5.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/stringtemplate-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/etc/dse:/etc/dse/cassandra:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/tools/lib/stress.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-all-2.1.15.1403.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-clientutil-2.1.15.1403.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-thrift-2.1.15.1403.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some times in the past while using and it is fixed now. I would suggest few options here:

- Check if any of the services is using the port 9042.
- Stop and restart Java and then restart c*. (This has helped me quite a few times)

Check if you do `nodetool status` what can you see.

The setting for this port number is present in the file `cassandra.yaml` in the location `/etc/dse/cassandra/` for Ubuntu. There is a line `native_transport_port: 9042`. Try changing that and restarting c*.

Share your update and we may try helping.

Comment: what do you mean by stop and restart Java ? Do I need to change anything else if I change the native_transport_port?

Comment: First of all, note down all the changes you are going to make, so that you can revert it back.
Stop C*, Kill java process ('ps -ef|grep java' and then kill the process id) and start C* and cqlsh again. If it does not work then only try to change the native_transport_port and check. In the same way try (ps -ef|grep) try to find which port your C* is using. and then update your cassandra.yaml file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After letting the machine run for 1,5 days, the machine seems to be back. I can't find the reason, just the behavirou with extrem GC operations, so could be a gc death spiral